# Why did Seska care about Tuvok's "betrayal"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, character-motivation

In "Worst Case Scenario," which occurs after Seska's death, she reveals through her hologram incarnation that she was upset at Tuvok for his betrayal of the Maquis crew, describing herself as:

> A holographic representation of Seska, one of the Maquis shipmates you
>   betrayed. I would have thought all that time you spent spying on us
>   might have given you a little more insight into the Maquis, but after
>   looking over what you've already written, I can see you need a little
>   help

I was wondering why she cared? At the time, she herself was a Cardassian spy who clearly had a very harsh personality and thought in terms of tactics. This kind of revenge seems unlike her.

I was wondering if there was any in- or out-of-universe explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Her in-universe actions were frankly baffling. The wildly inconsistent writing of her character was one of the real low points of Voyager

Comment: I thought it got pretty consistent after it was revealed that she was a spy.

Comment: Regardless of what she really was, if Tuvok had succeeded, she would have been just as arrested as the rest of the Maquis. Her sense of betrayal may have been part of her act since she was still "Bajoran" at the time.

Comment: It's also a great deal for her as a traitor herself - exposing the 'traitor' among her ranks and seeking justice from him lends massive credit to her being loyal to the cause, and on top of that removes a unifying leader figure from the group she's trying to disrupt.  Really, she has everything to gain from seeing Tuvok destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it was really good use of Cardassian character traits there. I would say watching Seska in "Voy" reminded me a lot of Dukat in "DS9". scheme within a scheme within a scheme. Some cruelty, seemingly inherent in Cardassian spies, indulgence in misdirection, machination, evading as much as possible... Seemingly unlikely revenge thirst is really very Cardassian-like.

I think the un-polite action of answering answer with an answer is in place: maybe it's not what she cared about was important, maybe it's *WHO is she really and* what she DID in it that really answers the question?

*[UPDATE in this style in text above]*

Comment: I don't think this answer explains her bizarre actions. Punishing Tuvok for being an infiltration agent when she herself is an infiltration agent...

Comment: I think it does. Her actions are not bizarre IF we take into account she is a Cardassian, who ARE cruel (of course not in their own eyes), vindictive (to the extreme), paranoidal and xenophobic, etc., etc. DS9 is full of such examples (Empok Nor, Garak training Bashir in Cardassian spy trade, traps and backup procedures buried deep in computers). You thinking on Seska like she was Human or Bajoran. She was Cardassian. And that's my point.